# I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file (SQLCODE: -902, SQLSTATE: 08001, GDSCODE: 335544344) Firebird 4.0.3

Tags: firebird, firebird-4.0

Having technical issue on old server (FB 2.1) we copied our DB to another virtual server as mentioned in the post title.

I set up the server last week:

1. There is also rule to allow access on 3050 port (`netstat` approves that Firebird is listening on it).
2. There are two DBs now: with aliases, so `aliases.conf`is configured.
3. To test the first one last week I wrote the following lines in `'firebird.conf'`:

```
DatabaseAccess = Restrict D:\Projects\db\

+

AuthServer = Srp256, Srp, Legacy_auth 
AuthClient = Srp256, Srp, Legacy_auth 
UserManager = Srp, Legacy_UserManager 
WireCrypt = Enabled
```

As was mentioned at one of the posts on stackoverflow. I can't found the correct solution.
`databases.conf`:

```
# ------------------------------
# List of known databases
# ------------------------------

#
# Makes it possible to specify per-database configuration parameters.
# See the list of them and description on file firebird.conf.
# To place that parameters in this file add them in curly braces
# after "alias = /path/to/database.fdb" line. Example:
#   big = /databases/bigdb.fdb
#   {
#       LockMemSize = 32M       # We know that bigdb needs a lot of locks
#       LockHashSlots = 19927   #   and big enough hash table for them
#   }
#

#
# Example Database:
#
employee.fdb = $(dir_sampleDb)/employee.fdb
employee = $(dir_sampleDb)/employee.fdb

#
# Master security database specific setup.
# Do not remove it until you understand well what are you doing!
#
security.db = $(dir_secDb)/security4.fdb
{
    RemoteAccess = false
    DefaultDbCachePages = 256
}

#
# Live Databases:
#
```

Screen is also attached.
[image]

Comment: Can you translate the OS error that is shown in Russian here? Also, please post the error as code-formatted text and not a screenshot.

Comment: In any case, the error suggest the alias is not resolved, and I gues the error is some file not found error or similar. Do you actually have an alias `Bee` in your databases.conf? Include the content of databases.conf in your question as well. To be clear, since Firebird 3, Firebird doesn't have an aliases.conf anymore, it now has databases.conf which serves a similar purpose. So if you just created a file aliases.conf in your Firebird 4 install, that is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasing of your question suggests that you have defined alias `Bee` in a file called `aliases.conf`, just like you used to do under Firebird 4.0. However, since Firebird 3.0, Firebird no longer uses that file, instead it uses `databases.conf` (which in addition to specifying aliases can hold database-specific configuration.

If that is the case, copy the content of `aliases.conf` to `databases.conf` and delete `aliases.conf`. The file `databases.conf` also contains some standard configuration for the security database, so don't just replace the files!

As an aside, if you only copied your database from Firebird 1.5 to Firebird 4.0 without backup and restore, this is not going to work. Firebird 4.0 can only open Firebird 4.0 (ODS 13.0) databases. In addition, there were some syntax and behavioural changes between Firebird 1.5 and Firebird 2.0 that may cause issues for your existing application if it relies on that syntax and behaviour (I highly recommend you check the Firebird 2.0, 2.1, 2.5, 3.0 and 4.0 [release notes](https://firebirdsql.org/en/release-notes/)).

Comment: After your suggestion, I got a new error: found 10.1, support 13.0. So ODS? How to properly do a backup?

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov In its simplest form, you need to backup the database under Firebird 1.5 with the Firebird 1.5 gbak, and restore it under Firebird 4.0 with the Firebird 4.0 gbak. Alternatively, you need to recreate the database structure and use a datapump tool to copy the data from the Firebird 1.5 database to the Firebird 4.0 database. See also [Short Firebird Migration Guide to Firebird 4.0](https://ib-aid.com/download/docs/fb4migrationguide.html) (though it only covers 2.5/3.0 to 4.0).

Comment: I'm going to read about backup,  but at first, I have also lost access to the previos DB (created using IBExpert UI, which was functioning before). It was created using FB 4.0. So how did deleting `aliases.conf` corrupted those settting, if you tell that it's outdated and has no use now?

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov I don't use IBExpert, so I can't say how it works or what could have happened, but if changing configuration in your Firebird server changes things in IBExpert, I would consider that a bug in IBExpert, and I think that's unlikely (especially as it is generally used for remote administration of multiple Firebird servers rather than local).

Comment: It's very strange, but when I delete line `Config = d:\Projects\db\config.fdb` from `databases.conf` and create `aliases.conf` again with that line: error is eliminated.

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov Sounds weird to me, but maybe IBExpert has special support for local aliases.conf, or maybe you're using an old version that doesn't know about databases.conf. I'd guess the workaround would be to add it to both, or maybe upgrade to a newer version. But to be clear, those are just guesses and things I'd explore when trying to investigate a thing like this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No, IBExpert just use bundled Fireird 2.5 Embedded for access to its configuration database by default. It is a weird tool.

Comment: @user13964273 That would suggest that the OP modified an `aliases.conf` in the IBExpert installation, and not in the Firebird installation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I found the answer when you directed me to `databases.conf`. After server installation I uncommented `DataAccess = Restrict <path to specific folder>` in the `firebird.conf` file. A the alias was the same as the database name in that folder it worked when I deleted alias from the `databases.conf`. When I insert the alias back it didn't work because the path to file included `.fdb` extension, but created file is `Config`.